# Keeping a local variable from getting destructed twice, how? heap corruption

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, memory

I've been having problems with my homework, regarding making a polynomial class and overloading some operators to work according to the class. I've done most of the thing, but I seem to be having a problem with my destructor, or my functions.

The problem is, according to my debugging(if I did it right, which I think I did), the returning value of my + operator function get's destructed twice, when used with my copy constructor, in something like this :

```
//polynomials p1 and p2 are declared and given values beforehand
Polynomial p5=Polynomial();
p5=p1+p2;
```

This results in a heap corruption error.

Here's my header code:

```
#ifndef POLYNOMIAL_H_
#define POLYNOMIAL_H_
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Polynomial
{
public:
    Polynomial();
    Polynomial(int);
    ~Polynomial();
    Polynomial(const Polynomial &);
    int getOrder() const; 
    double getCoefficient(int) const; 
    void setOrder(int);
    void setCoefficient(int,double);
    const Polynomial &operator=(const Polynomial &);
    const bool &operator==(const Polynomial &);
    const double &operator()(double &);
    const bool &operator!=(const Polynomial &);

    friend Polynomial operator+(const Polynomial &poly1, const Polynomial &poly2);
    friend Polynomial &operator+=(Polynomial &poly1,const  Polynomial &poly2);
    friend Polynomial operator-(const Polynomial &poly1, const Polynomial &poly2);
    friend Polynomial &operator-=( Polynomial &poly1,const  Polynomial &poly2);
    friend Polynomial operator*(Polynomial poly1,double num);
private:
    int order;
    double *coefficient;
};


#endif
```

and here's my overloaded + function, it's not pretty, but my problem is not the calculations, it's the memory. I declared it as a friend function in the class, and by my homework rules, i need to implement it in the main.cpp file as a free function, and not as a member function.

```
   Polynomial operator+(const Polynomial &poly1, const Polynomial &poly2) //the overloaded +operator. makes the order of the result the bigger order and adds the coefficients for all the orders. returns the result. 
{
    Polynomial result;


    if(poly1.order >= poly2.order)
    {
        result.setOrder(poly1.order);
        for(int i=poly1.order;i>poly2.order;i--)
        {
            result.setCoefficient(poly1.order-i, poly1.coefficient[poly1.order-i]);
        }
        for (int i =poly2.getOrder(); i>=0;i--)
        {
            result.setCoefficient(poly1.order-i,poly1.coefficient[poly1.order-i]+poly2.coefficient[poly2.order-i]);
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        result.setOrder(poly2.order);

        for(int i=poly2.order;i>poly1.order;i--)
        {
            result.setCoefficient(poly2.order-i, poly2.coefficient[poly2.order-i]);
        }
        for (int i =poly1.order; i>=0;i--)
        {
            result.setCoefficient(poly2.order-i,poly1.coefficient[poly1.order-i]+poly2.coefficient[poly2.order-i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

We were also required to overload the = operator, and here's that function if it's needed.

```
    const Polynomial &Polynomial::operator=(const Polynomial &poly)
{
    if(this!=&poly)
    {
        if(order==poly.order)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<=order;i++)
            {
                coefficient[i]=poly.coefficient[i];
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            coefficient=new double[poly.order];
            order=poly.order;
            for(int i=0;i<=order;i++)
            {
                coefficient[i]=poly.coefficient[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Please keep in mind that I'm really a beginner in coding and c++, and I appreciate any help you give.

EDIT: Adding the deep copy constructor.

```
 Polynomial::Polynomial(const Polynomial &copy) //deep copy constructor
{
    order=copy.order;
    coefficient=new double[copy.order];
    for (int i=0;i<=order;i++)
    {
        coefficient[i]=copy.coefficient[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide code for Polynomial(const Polynomial &); as well?

Comment: added the code for Polynomial(const Polynomial &)

Comment: Your copy assignment operator is leaking memory. You never delete the old coefficient array before creating a new one. Also, have you considered just using std::vector here? It would get rid of the memory leak and any implementation worth anything would have caught the out-of-bounds access in debug mode too.

Comment: So do I need to delete[] coefficient before I create the new coefficient? I would LOVE to use the vector here, but my homework assignment states that I need to do this using dynamic arrays. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @SebastianRedl, but memory leak is hardly a reason for heap corruption. I would guess that the problem IS around the coefficient, but somewhere else (in on of the other functions), maybe setCoefficient?

Comment: through my debugging, I saw I got the heap corruption error when the destructor was called, could the problem's reason still be another function?

Comment: unary operators like `+` or `==` is better to implement as members when binary operators like `+=` is better to implement as free (optionally friend) functions.

Comment: Actually, your copy constructor seems to be faulty. You allocate an array of doubles and in the for loop your index go out of bounds, when `i == order`.

Comment: I fixed that, but I'm still having the heap corruption error.

Comment: well, not anymore. thanks a lot to those who helped me, i figured it all out.

Answer (score 1):

You allocate memory for `poly.order` doubles, but in your for loop last index would be `poly.order` while it should `poly.order-1` changing <= to < will solve that.

```
   coefficient=new double[poly.order];//This is memory leak previous coefficient needs to be deleted
    order=poly.order;
    for(int i=0;i<=order;i++)//<= will lead to overflow and heap corruption
    {
        coefficient[i]=poly.coefficient[i];
    }
```

Comment: Yes I figured it out, seems I have to make  coefficient=new double[poly.order] into  coefficient=new double[poly.order+1]. Thanks a lot.

Comment: And don't forget to delete old buffer prior to allocation of bigger one.

Answer (score 0):

In your copy constructor and your overloaded `operator=` you are iterating one extra time when you copy the `cofficient` array:

```
  coefficient=new double[copy.order];
  for (int i=0;i<=order;i++)
                ^^
```

That should be be `<`, you have allocated `order` space but you are iterating `order+1` times. You also need to call `delete []` the old `coefficient` array as well. Normally the safe way to do this is allocate to a temporary first and modify that and if all those potentially unsafe operations are successful then you can `delete` and assign the temporary to `coefficient`. You can see this SO post on [`Rule of Three`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) for a solid explanation on what you need to do when using a `copy constructor` and `assignment`.

Comment: ah ah yeah i got it. i have to make all the new allocations copy.order+1, since that's the amount of coefficients i need to have. Thanks a lot for the answers.

Comment: do i need to delete anything in the copy constructor, since I'm creating it from scratch, or do i need to call delete[] for the = operator only?

Comment: @ArdıçSönmez I explained it a little bit in my updated post but you should see the `Rule of Three` post I added this will explain in detail what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot, as I'm still new, I'm having problems getting the core principles in my head.